# Objectify - set filter if not null

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a resource with a few nullable query params.
I want to return the relevant entities from the DB (GAE DataStore)
Do I have a shorter or prettier way to do it (I'm looking for something like  'set if not null' method) ?

This is my code:

```
var query: Query<Kind> = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(Kind::class.java)

if (name != null) {
query = query.filter("name ==", name)
} else if (gender != null) {
query = query.filter("gender ==", gender)
} else if (address != null) {
query = query.filter("timing ==", address)
}

return query....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing in Objectify.

If you have a lot of parameters to use in filter, a popular approach is a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern:

```
public class QueryBuilder {
    public static final Class<Kind> TYPE = Kind.class;
    private Query<Kind> query;

    public QueryBuilder() {
        query = ofy().load().type(TYPE);
    }

    public QueryBuilder name(String name) {
        return setIfNotNull("name", name);
    }

    public QueryBuilder gender(String gender) {
        return setIfNotNull("gender", gender);
    }

    public QueryBuilder address(String address) {
        return setIfNotNull("address", address);
    }

    public Query<Kind> build() {
        return query;
    }

    private QueryBuilder setIfNotNull(String name, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            query = query.filter(name, value);
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

And then:

```
Query<Kind> query = new QueryBuilder()
        .name(name)
        .address(address)
        .gender(gender)
        .build();
```

Comment: thanks
After investigation I have fond that in kotlin extention method is the correct solution  .